# nagios (Last Notification: N/A (notification 0))

Tags: nagios

I can't figure out but for some reason Nagios doesn't send me an alert on some of the services that I monitor, I was wondering if someone can help me out a bit.

this is service

```
define service {
    hostgroup_name          nrpe-disk
    service_description     disk
    use             alarm,check
    check_command           check_nrpe1!check_disk
    register            1
    }
```

here is my command

```
define command {
       command_name                         check_nrpe1
       command_line                         $USER1$/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

here is service template

```
define service {
       name                                 alarm
       notification_interval                0
       notification_period                  247
       notification_options                 w,u,r,c,f,s
       notifications_enabled                1
       contact_groups                       staff
       register                         0

}
```

```
define command {
       command_name                         notify-host-by-email
       command_line                         /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Host Alert: $HOSTNAME$ is $HOSTSTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
}   

define command {
       command_name                         notify-host-by-pager
       command_line                         /usr/bin/printf "%b" "Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\nHost: $HOSTNAME$\nState: $HOSTSTATE$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nInfo: $HOSTOUTPUT$" | /usr/bin/mail $CONTACTPAGER$
}   

define command {
       command_name                         notify-service-by-email
       command_line                         /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
}   

define command {
       command_name                         notify-service-by-pager
       command_line                         /usr/bin/printf "%b" "Notification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$" | /usr/bin/mail $CONTACTPAGER$
}
```

```
define contactgroup {
    contactgroup_name                   staff
    alias                               XXXXXXXX
    members                             XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX
    }
```

```
define contact {
    contact_name                        XXXXXXX XXXXXX
    alias                               XXXXXXXXX
    host_notifications_enabled          1
    service_notifications_enabled       1
    host_notification_period            247
    service_notification_period         247
    host_notification_options           d,u,r,f,s
    service_notification_options        w,u,c,r,f,s
    host_notification_commands          notify-host-by-email,notify-host-by-pager
    service_notification_commands       notify-service-by-email,notify-service-by-pager
    email                               XXXXXXXXX@XXXXXXXX.XXX
    pager                               XXXXXXXXXX@messaging.sprintpcs.com
    }
```

Comment: Does everything seem right in the web interface?

Comment: yes, it seems fine on web, other where it says 0 notifications has been sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see it mentioned in your question or any of the answers but have you checked the `nagios.cfg` file for the *enable_notifications* setting? Is it set to **0** or **1**?

Also is this only happening on a given service notification or is it affecting all notifications? If it's all I would suspect that enable_notifications is set to 0 in the nagios.cfg file. If so try changing it to 1 and restarting Nagios.

Comment: of course, if this wouldn't be enabled i wouldn't get any notifications, that's why i said it doesn't send an alert on *some* of the services, not all, just *some* !

Comment: OP mentioned that notifications are sent for _some_ notifications - why is this the accepted answer when it clearly isn't? (I'm having the same problem and look for an answer as well)

Answer (score 4):

The nagios debug log helped me diagnose a similar issue. It was near the end of my nagios.cfg

```
debug_level=32
debug_file=/var/log/nagios3/nagios.debug
debug_verbosity=2
```

restart nagios, then tail the `nagios.debug` file; it'll show you something like:

```
[1416254305.106042] [032.0] [pid=928] ** Service Notification Attempt ** Host: 'myhost', Service: 'myservice', Type: 0, Options: 0, Current State: 2, Last Notification: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
[1416254305.106106] [032.0] [pid=928] Notification viability test passed.
[1416254305.106114] [032.1] [pid=928] Current notification number: 1 (incremented)
[1416254305.106120] [032.2] [pid=928] Creating list of contacts to be notified.
[1416254305.106137] [032.1] [pid=928] Service notification will NOT be escalated.
[1416254305.106174] [032.1] [pid=928] Adding normal contacts for service to notification list.
[1416254305.106185] [032.2] [pid=928] Adding contact 'mycontact' to notification list.
[1416254305.106219] [032.2] [pid=928] ** Attempting to notifying contact 'mycontact'...
[1416254305.106449] [032.2] [pid=928] ** Checking service notification viability for contact 'mycontact'...
[1416254305.106463] [032.2] [pid=928] We shouldn't notify this contact about CRITICAL service states.
[1416254305.106474] [032.0] [pid=928] No contacts were notified.  Next possible notification time: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969
[1416254305.106481] [032.0] [pid=928] 0 contacts were notified.
```

In my case, I had a bad contact `service_notification_options`, which prevented the initial notification from going out, which blocked all my escalations (if we never send notification 0, we can't ever get to notification 1)

Comment: The hint to `nagios.debug` was helpful indeed: I experienced the same issue because "`Notification blocked because the object is currently flapping`". After fixing the [flap detection](http://www.naemon.org/documentation/usersguide/flapping.html) settings, notifications for this service were being sent again.

Answer (score 0):

My first step would be to try defining all the parameters directly rather than depending on inheritance.  Avoid groups, too, if you can.  This at least gives you a clean starting place to debug from.

```
define service {
    host_name                  XXXXXXX
    service_description        disk
    notification_interval      0
    notification_period        247
    notifications_enabled      1
    contacts                   XXXXXXX
    check_command              check_nrpe1!check_disk
    }
```

You might also want to try switching notification_interval to something else, even leave it out (defaults to 60).  Just until you get it working.

Comment: then change one thing at a time, checking that it's working every time.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have a "notify-by-email" section in your commands config file?  Here's the relevant section from mine:

## 'notify-by-email' command definition

define command{
        command_name    send-email
        command_line    /usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios  *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$" | /bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ alert - $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
        }

Can your system send mail in general?  Can you use "mail -s test foo@bar.com", then type some text, a blank line and finally Ctrl-D to send?

Comment: yes, i'm able to send out an emails, also some of services are working fine in terms of notifications and some not...

Comment: I would then suspect your group configuration is not correct.  You are in the notification group for some services and not for others.

Another answer could be that you don't have notification types set up correctly for some services or groups.

Comment: i added to main question contactgroups and contacts

Comment: Is 247 a valid time period?

Does running /path/to/nagios/executable -v /path/to/nagios/config/file/nagios.cfg give you any errors?

Comment: 247 is a valid time period. no errors when running pre-flight check

Answer (score -1):

changing

```
register 0
```

to

```
register 1
```

in your "alarm" service might help.

Comment: you probably missed it, but that was service template, all templates must have register 0

Answer (score -1):

Where's the service-template for *check* ? Since you're using with templates alarm and check.
I guess *check* overwrites *alarm*...

```
define service {
    hostgroup_name          nrpe-disk
    service_description     disk
    use             alarm,check
    check_command           check_nrpe1!check_disk
    register            1
    }
```

perhaps *notification_failure_criteria* can help you

Do you really have a *notification_period* called *247* or rather *24x7*?

You get a correct feedback from your command (so there should be a alarm?)?
you tested the command on the command-line (as your nagios-user)?

Comment: notification_failure_criteria that's service dependencies, I didn't get to that part yet.

as far as one template goes over the other one, unlikely as some of services are working and some are not, they both using same templates (alarm and check), my time period is 247, not 24x7 if my time period would be incorrect nagios would complain while starting, it doesn't, yes I did test everything manually as nagios user and it works

Comment: What about your host-template? Or your host-group(templates)?
Since you didn't post them we can't loo through them.
Please post or check those.
(-1? My Answer makes sense, so why "-1"?)